# Block Diagram 2nd Butterworth Low-pass

Tags: filters, frequency, modulation, differential-equation

I would like to represent a second-order butterworth low-pass filter in a block diagram, how can I get started?

As per the attached image

[image]

Comment: Time continuous or time discrete? Are we talking about an algorithm or some physical contraption (like a circuit) ? If it's a circuit: active or passive ?

Comment: It's a continuous-time low-pass second-order Butterworth filter, and the block diagram should be in accordance with the differential equation of my system. In my block diagram I tried to use the KLC method to arrive at a possible solution

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wbRmwuMXinqI

Comment: This is a Sallen-Key circuit and pretty well known for all-pole 2nd order analog filter.  There is lotsa lit out there you can find.